# Looping a statically allocated array, outside of c99 mode?

Tags: c, c99, loops

This is in reference to a solution posted on:  [Looping a fixed size array without defining its size in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969588/looping-a-fixed-size-array-without-defining-its-size-in-c)

Here's my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static const char *foo[] = {
           "this is a test",
           "hello world",
           "goodbye world",
           "123", 
           NULL
    };

    for (char *it = foo[0]; it != NULL; it++) {
        printf ("str %s\n", it);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Trying to compile this gives:

```
gcc -o vararray vararray.c
vararray.c: In function ‘main’:
vararray.c:14: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
vararray.c:14: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
```

Comment: Clarify:  C99 mode "forbidden", and you need the work-around  --  OR  --  you are open to using C99 mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides the initialization in the for loop, you're incrementing in the wrong place. I think this is what you mean (note that I'm not exactly a C guru):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static const char *foo[] = {
           "this is a test",
           "hello world",
           "goodbye world",
           "123", 
           NULL
    };
    const char **it;
    for (it=foo; *it != NULL; it++) {
        printf ("str %s\n", *it);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Yep, it++ makes sense only for **.

Answer (score 6):

1. Your loop variable `it` is of type `char*`, the contents of the array are of type `const char*`. If you change `it` to be also a `const char*` the warning should go away.
2. You declare `it` inside the for statement, this is not allowed in C before C99. Declare `it` at the beginning of `main()` instead.
   Alternatively you can add `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` to your gcc flags to enable the C99 language features.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-std=c99` option when compiling your code in order to use the `C99` features.

Change `it` to `const char*` type ( to remove the warnings)

Answer (score 0):

Before C99, declaring that character pointer in the for loop is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things to have this compile without warnings: declare the iterator `const char* it`, and do it at the beginning of the function and not in the loop statement.