# (C/C++) Size of an array of chars

Tags: c++, c, arrays

How to find out the lenght of an array of chars that is not null terminated/zero terminated or anything like that?

Because I wrote a writeFile function and I wanna get rid of that 'len' parameter.

```
int writeFile(FILE * handle, char * data, int len)
{
    fseek(handle, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for(int i=0; i <= len; i++)
        fputc(data[i], handle);
}
```

Comment: You can't, that's what `len` is there for, unless you just want to combine the two in a `struct` or something, or use `std::string` or a `vector` or something else because your question is tagged C++.

Comment: For C++, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2404697/103167  By the way, you're actually writing `len+1` characters.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get rid of the len parameter. The computer is not an oracle to guess your intentions. But you can use the `fwrite()` function which will write your data much more efficiently than `fputc()`.

Answer (score 1):

there is no *portable* way*, that is why sentinel values like null terminators are used.

In fact, its better to specify a length parameter, as it allows partial writes from data buffers (though in your case I would use a `size_t`/`std::size_t` for the length).

*you could try using `_msize` on windows, but it will lead to tears.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define writeFile(handle, data) writeFileImpl(handle, data, sizeof data)
```

Comment: what happens if an array thats decayed to a pointer has been passed, or a text string from `malloc`? :) in this case I think a macro would be way too evil, as sooner or later, someone will assume that it works on everything...

Comment: @Necrolis: The C++ solution I linked in my comment is DEFINITELY better, since it protects against reporting the size of a pointer.  But if you gotta have something that works in C, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

As Seith Carnegie commented and others answered, you cannot do that (getting the length of *any* array of char).

Some C libraries provide you with an extension giving an (over-sized) estimate of the length of *heap-allocated* memory (e.g. pointers obtained by `malloc`).

If you uses [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) (which is very useful!), it gives you in [`<gc/gc.h>`](https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc/blob/master/include/gc.h) the `GC_size` function.

But when the array of char is inside a structure, or on the call stack, there is no way to get its size at runtime. Only your program knows it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of the len parameter unless you have another way of determining the length of your data (usually by using a null terminator).  This is because C and C++ don't store the length of the data.  Furthermore, programmers might appreciate the len parameter.  You don't always want to write out all the bytes in your array.