# Size of operator return conflict

Tags: c++, c, size

here is some code

```
class DengkleTryingToSleep{
public:
int minDucks(int ducks[]);
int temp(int ducks[]){
int size=sizeof(ducks);
cout<<"sizeof="<<size<<"\n";
}
};


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
DengkleTryingToSleep dt;
int arr[]={9,3,6,4};

cout<<"sizeof "<<sizeof(arr);
cout<<"\nsizeof from function "<<dt.temp(arr);

return 0; 
}
```

and output of this is

```
sizeof 16
sizeof from function sizeof=8
```

and i have no idea how this is working because it returns 16 (as expected when called inside main)
and returns 8 when called from the function

Comment: i admire your naming conventions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reliably get size of C-style array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404567/how-to-reliably-get-size-of-c-style-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this function:

```
int temp(int ducks[])
```

is exactly equivalent this function:

```
int temp(int *ducks)
```

There is NO DIFFERENCE at all. No difference. So no matter what you pass, whether an array or a pointer, it will become a pointer inside the function.

That means, when you write `sizeof(ducks)` in your function, it is exactly equivalent to `sizeof(int*)`, which returns `8` on your machine (I guess, your machine has 64-bit OS where the size of pointer is `8` bytes).

If you want to pass an array, and don't it decay into pointer type, then do this:

```
template<size_t N>
int temp(int (&ducks)[N])
{
    int size=sizeof(ducks);
    cout<<"sizeof="<<size<<"\n";
}
```

Now it will print `16`. Note that inside the function `N` represents the count of items in the array. So in your case, it would be `4`, as there are `4` elements in the array. It means, if you need the length of the array, you don't need to calculate it as `sizeof(bucks)/sizeof(int)`, as you already know the length of the array which is `N`.

Also note that there is a limitation in this approach: now you cannot pass dynamically allocated array:

```
int *a = new int[10];
dt.temp(a); //compilation error

//but you can pass any statically declared array
int b[100], c[200];
dt.temp(b); //ok - N becomes 100
dt.temp(c); //ok - N becomes 200
```

---

But in C++, you've a better option here: use `std::vector<int>`.

```
int temp(std::vector<int> & ducks)
{
     std::cout << ducks.size() << std::endl;
}

//call it as
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; //C++11 only, or else : use .push_back()
dt.temp(v);
```

Comment: exactly but i want to calculate its length using sizeof(array)/sizeof(int) and for that what should i do?

Comment: @fsl4faisal: Updated. see it.

Comment: @fsl4faisal and if you don't want to use templates , then you have no other option but to write : `int temp(int (&ducks)[4])`

Comment: what are you doing in here i am not getting it and one more thing that i can not manipulate the arguments in my program and i can only use int array[] as an argument

Comment: well can i use vectors in here when calling the function from main because then i can use its in built function?

Comment: @fsl4faisal: Why can't you use that?

Comment: @fsl4faisal: Yes. `std::vector<int>` is best option here.

Answer (score 5):

Because arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function. You're getting the size of a pointer in your `temp` function.

If you need to know the length of an array in a function ... you have to pass that in as well.

Comment: @Brain so why its size is down to 8 and not some other value what computation is performed exactly in here

Comment: Because apparently pointers are 64 bits on your system (8 bytes). You will get `8` if you do ... `sizeof(int*)` or `sizeof(char*)` etc. A pointer holds the memory address of the thing it points to. On 64bit systems they're generally 64bits.

Comment: so what if i have to calculate its length inside that function using sizeof(array)/sizeof(int) right now its returning a wrong value

Comment: You *can't* do that. As I said, you have to pass in the length along with the array. e.g. ... `temp(int ducks[], int ducksLength)`. If you need to know the *size* you'd have to do something like `temp(int ducks[], int ducksLength, size_t memberSize)` and multiply; `ducksLength * memberSize`

Comment: well thats a pain because i can't take more than one argument to the function its like one of its prerequisite

Comment: Arrays don't always decay to pointers.They don't when used with `sizeof`. OP gets the `sizeof` of the pointer because S/He passes an pointer to `sizeof` not an array.

Comment: @Als well i have pasted the code and it returns 8 try it for yourself

Comment: @Als - that's because `sizeof()` isn't actually a function, it's an operator;  the parenthesis are actually optional.

Comment: @BrianRoach well its still returning same i have removed the parenthesis

Comment: @fsl4faisal - correct. There's no way to pass an actual array to a function; it will always decay to a pointer. Als was contending that this didn't always happen, e.g. `sizeof(arr)` in your `main()` returning `16` - the reason is that `sizeof` *isn't* a function.